# Retrieve the first data from multiple almost the same or correct data in table

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

How can i retrieve a data from query that has multiple the same data?. Something like this. I have a data representation like this:

```
Id        Time              Status
-------------------------------------
1   2019-09-09 09:00:00       1
2   2019-09-09 09:02:36       1
3   2019-09-09 09:06:00       1
4   2019-09-09 09:10:11       1
5   2019-09-09 17:00:00       2
6   2019-09-09 17:05:00       2
7   2019-09-10 09:00:00       1
8   2019-09-10 09:02:32       1
9   2019-09-10 09:02:38       1
10   2019-09-10 17:00:00       2
11   2019-09-10 17:00:30       2
```

Now i want to return something like these with parameter where `date = 2019-09-09` :

```
1   2019-09-09 09:00:00       1
5   2019-09-09 17:00:00       2
```

i want to return the first data that was inserted.

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0 or an earlier version?

Comment: @Martin mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.30-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the mysql tag and replaced it with mariadb. Please tag appropriately as it is important for identifying how to solve problems

Comment: @Martin thanks i'll wait for another best answer

Comment: You should check out Tim Biegeleisen's answer below.  His second solution works in your version of MariaDB (10.1.30), and the first works in 10.2 and above

Comment: @Martin thanks i've tried his answer and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT id, Time, Status
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY Time) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Time >= '2019-09-09' AND Time < '2019-09-10'
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Status;
```

If you are using a version of MySQL earlier than 8+, then use:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.Time, t1.Status
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Status, MIN(Time) AS min_time
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Time >= '2019-09-09' AND Time < '2019-09-10'
    GROUP BY Status
) t2
    ON t1.Status = t2.Status AND t1.Time = t2.min_time
WHERE
    t1.Time >= '2019-09-09' AND t1.Time < '2019-09-10'
ORDER BY
    t1.Status;
```

Comment: SELECT
tbl_attendance.time,
tbl_attendance.`status`
FROM
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STATUS ORDER BY time) rn FROM tbl_attendance WHERE time >= '2019-09-09' AND Time < '2019-09-10'
)t 
WHERE rn = 1 
ORDER BY status

Comment: @JcJohn That is because ROW_NUMBER() is only available from MySQL 8.0 and later

Comment: @JcJohn I believe my syntax to be correct.  Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Martin any suggestions for the version i've got ? or replacement of Row_number?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ROW_NUMBER() isn't available in Maria 10.1.30.  It was introduced in 10.2

Answer (score 0):

The following table and query would solve your problem:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST 
(
    ID TINYINT,
    DATE SMALLDATETIME,
    STATUS TINYINT,
)

INSERT INTO  TEST VALUES (1,   '2019-09-09 09:00:00',       1),
(2 ,  '2019-09-09 09:02:36'   ,    1),
(3 ,  '2019-09-09 09:06:00'   ,    1),
(4   ,'2019-09-09 09:10:11'   ,    1),
(5   ,'2019-09-09 17:00:00'   ,    2),
(6 ,  '2019-09-09 17:05:00'   ,    2),
(7  , '2019-09-10 09:00:00'   ,    1),
(8  , '2019-09-10 09:02:32'   ,    1),
(9 ,  '2019-09-10 09:02:38'    ,   1),
(10 ,  '2019-09-10 17:00:00'   ,    2),
(11  ,' 2019-09-10 17:00:30'   ,    2)

SELECT STATUS,MIN(DATE) AS INPUTDATE FROM TEST WHERE CAST(DATE AS DATE)='2019-09-09'
GROUP BY STATUS
```

> Output

```
STATUS  INPUTDATE
1   2019-09-09 09:00:00
2   2019-09-09 17:00:00
```